# Free and maintained box2d editor

Tags: gratis, open-source, game, game-development

I'm looking for a free map 2d / box 2d editor for Libgdx. [VisEditor](https://vis.kotcrab.com/) is deprecated, [overlap2d](https://github.com/UnderwaterApps/overlap2d) is dead.

I want something like VisEditor, free and maintained, preferably open source. It must work on Ubuntu.